# Transfer data Javascript to PHP (on click on confirm box)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wanted that when the user clicks on 'Ok', I write a string in a file (.txt) on my server.

```
 <script> if(confirm('capteur') == true){ /*write on a file*/ } </script>
```

I thought that I can simply write JavaScript to do it, but it doesn't work that way. So, I want to transfer data from JavaScript to PHP, which indicates if the PHP must write (or not) in the file.

```
 <script> if(confirm('capteur') == true){ /*send data to PHP*/ } </script>
 <?php $var = //data send from Javascript
   if($var==1){
       $fichier = fopen("log.txt",'a');
       $puts($fichier,"restart");
       fclose($fichier);
   }
 ?>
```

I tried some solutions (Ajax, redirection, POST/GET, jquery) but I never managed to transfer the data.

Here my test with jquery:

```
<script> if(confirm('capteur') == true){ 
               var variableToSend = 1;
               $.post('jv.php', {variable: variableToSend});
         } </script>

<?php $var = $_POST['variable']; ?>
```

And here with GET/POST :

```
<script>if(confirm('capteur') == true){
           var xhr_object = null;
           if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
               xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
           }else{
               alert("Your browser doesn't support the XMLHTTPRequest object");
           }

            xhr_object.open("POST", "jv.php", true);
            xhr_object.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr_object.send("variable=1");

            /*xhr_object.open("GET","jv.php?variable=1",true); xhr_object.send();*/
        }
</script>
```

What should be the best/simplest option?

Comment: What was the problem with the GET/POST?

Comment: When i try to display the $_POST['variable'], nothing appears

Comment: Well probably, I'll try this way

Comment: @Anonymous no, It's not a duplicate. Op is having a clear issue with interfacing javascript and php. He obviously looked at using jquery and was not opposed to using it.

Comment: @Anonymous how? He used `post` which is an ajax function in jquery

Comment: @Anonymous in fact, outside of setting cache, the first answer and Op's calls are identical.

Comment: @iismathwizard Hmm... looking at it again, the problem is less clear than I thought.

Comment: @Bacara How did you check what `$_POST['variable']` contains?

Comment: @Anonymous I *think* op believes that he can send, in an ajax call, the variable from javascript to php on the same page and expect it to be processed on the already rendered page. Obviously, this isn't how php works and he should be using `.done(function(data){});` to get a result from a separate php page.

Comment: @iismathwizard Yea, that's probably it.

Comment: @Anonymous I try to check with an echo and a print.

Comment: @iismathwizard yes I will try in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should try to avoid using:
   `confirm("capteur") == true`
   since that expression is exactly equivalent to
   `confirm("capteur")`
2. Try the following with jquery:

   ```
   var variableToSend = 1;
   $.post("someFile.php", {variable: variableToSend});
   ```

   in `someFile.php`

   ```
   <?php
       if(isset($_POST["variable"]))
       {
           $var = $_POST["variable"];
           //do stuff with $var here
       }
   ?>
   ```

Also, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how PHP works. All of the processing that PHP does occurs before you even see the resultant page. If you use ajax to send data to a PHP page, nothing will update on your current page unless you do something with the page result and update your current page appropriately.

Try this to understand a little better:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(confirm("click ok!"))
            {
                 $.post("myphpfile.php", {data: "ok"})
                       .done(function(data)
                            {
                                alert(data);
                            });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

*in myphpfile.php*

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["data"]))
    {
        print "your message: " . $_POST["data"];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way in my opinion is the Ajax method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(confirm('capteur') == true) { 
        var variableToSend = 1;

        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "jv.php",
          type: 'POST',
          cache: false,
          data: {variable: variableToSend}
        });
    }
</script>
```

The content of the file jv.php should be something like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['variable'])) {
    file_put_contents('log.txt', $_POST['variable'], FILE_APPEND);
}
```